# Visual Force Page in a standard layout. Causing problem because of height limit

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I have created a visual force page that displays all the approval history steps. I have added that to the Standard Layout of opportunity and I have found out due to height restriction it is not displaying all steps but only displays 3 steps and and rest are hidded. I am attaching two screen shots where one is from visual force page on layout another is from Approval history Related list.

VF Page 
[image]

Another with Related List 
[image]

I have tried on VF page with  I have also tried using   but none of this seems helping.

Any suggetions?

I want either that page to scroll or to increase the height ? Any idea how can I get that block to scroll to display all the details in approval hsitory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK SO I have managed to do that with the help of W3schools. Just incase if someone need help for this in future. Here is what needed to be done.

Add Style tags to write you CSS code on top of the page. After  tab

```
  <style>
        div.scroll
        {
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 200px;
        }

    </style>
```

and use `<div class="scroll"> </div>` tab to wrap up rest of the code on the page. Before `</apex:page>`

You are good to go.

Comment: So basically, @dotmiko's answer was correct.

Comment: yes. His answer was correct However I have added little more detail for the exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

If its a visualforce page, you could try wrapping the whole section inside a div then use the overflow css (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to make it scrollable.

Comment: Nope, that does not work . See here is my code for the page. This should scroll after overflow CSS but that does not help. 
<apex:page extensions="Controller_Approval_History_Override" standardController="Opportunity"  >
     <div>
    <style>
        div.scroll
        {
        overflow: scroll;
        }
    
    </style>
   
  <apex:messages />
    
    <apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" title="Lease Action Approval History" subject="{!Opportunity.id}" >
                    
    </apex:relatedList>
  </div>
</apex:page>

Comment: Sorry for the bad alignments .I couldn't align it in comemnt here